# How do I use the buddypress username in a shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, buddypress, ob-start

I'm trying to link to Buddypress groups, and I need the username of the logged in user to do this.  Here is my current shortcode, which is fine, but just outputs // in the URL with no username between.

```
// Add Shortcode
function my_groups_button() {
ob_start(); ?>
<a href="https://acaffiliates.coach/members/<?php echo bp_core_get_username($user_id); ?>/groups/"> My Groups</a>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'my-groups-button', 'my_groups_button' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the username, just the user id.

```
function my_groups_button() {
   ob_start();
   ?>
   <a href="<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain( bp_loggedin_user_id() ); ?>groups/">My Groups</a>
   <?php
   return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'my-groups-button', 'my_groups_button' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get the buddypress username inside the shortcode.

```
function my_groups_button() {
   ob_start();
   $user_name = bp_core_get_user_displayname( bp_loggedin_user_id() );
   // or bp_get_displayed_user_fullname();
   ?>
   <a href="https://acaffiliates.coach/members/<?php echo $user_name; ?>/groups/"> My Groups</a>
   <?php
   return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'my-groups-button', 'my_groups_button' );
```